# "In between" for Lagrange's theorem for series

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Everywhere I look, Lagrange Remainder Theorem is stated as

> Let $f$ be $k +1$ continuously differentiable, …, then **there is a number $c$** in **between** $x$ and $a$ such that

$$R_k(x) = \frac{f^{k+1}(c)(x-a)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

When they say "in between", do they just mean that we need consider when $x <a$ or $x > a$?